# Python 3 Change focus back to the command line in windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, setfocus

So I have this script I'm running in Python 3 on a windows 7 box that uses tkinter to prompt the user for a file name then uses win32com.client to open this file in Excel. This all works great, however after all of this Excel has focus and the user has to find his command line window and manually give it focus in order to be able to continue interacting with the script. Anyone know of any tricks where the script forces the command window running the script to take the focus again? Here are some relevant code snippets.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import win32com.client as win32 #pip install pypiwin32
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
strWBin = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select spreadsheet",filetypes = (("Excel files","*.xlsx"),("Text Files","*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")))
app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
app.Visible = True
wbin = app.Workbooks.Open (strWBin,0,True)
```

Comment: Just before starting Excel, try locking calls to `SetForegroundWindow` as follows: `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True);` `user32.LockSetForegroundWindow(1)`. Then after Excel creates its window, raise the console to the top Z order via `win32gui.SetWindowPos(win32console.GetConsoleWindow(), win32con.HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOSIZE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE)`.

Comment: What do I need to define to make this work, for example where does ctypes and wind32gui come from?

Comment: [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) is in the standard library. win32gui is from the PyWin32 extensions that are commonly used in Windows, which you pip installed as the [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32) package. You could do it all with ctypes if you don't want an external dependency, but you already have PyWin32 installed.

Comment: After figuring out all the different thing that needed to be imported I finally got the script to run. The only thing it did was to cause the command line window to blink, which is something I guess. I tried this both on my Win10 box and my Win 7 box.

Comment: Try this example: `import win32gui, win32console, win32event, ctypes, subprocess; user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True); user32.LockSetForegroundWindow(1); p = subprocess.Popen('notepad'); win32event.WaitForInputIdle(p._handle, 1000); win32gui.SetWindowPos(win32console.GetConsoleWindow(), win32con.HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOSIZE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE)`

Comment: In this case, `LockSetForegroundWindow` prevents notepad from stealing input focus (e.g. for keyboard input), `WaitForInputIdle` waits for notepad to create its window on top of the console, and `SetWindowPos` moves the console window to the top in the Z order.

Comment: You missed importing win32con, other than that this worked perfectly. When I tried to substitute the subprocess line that opened notepad with this line that gives me a handle into excel `app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
win32event.WaitForInputIdle(app._handle, 1000)` I get and error _AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x34883504>' object has no attribute '_handle'_

Comment: So do you think I'm SOL?

Comment: Interestingly word does not exhibit the same behaviour as Excel. When I use `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('word.Application')` to open up a word document, word remains in the background by default no tricks needed. Starting to think this is an excel issue :-(

Comment: Calling `WaitForInputIdle` on a process handle is just an example of waiting for the process to display its window before calling `SetWindowPos`. In your case, you don't have a process handle to wait on, but you could do something else like repeatedly poll the top-level windows for the Excel window. For that you can use `win32gui.EnumWindows` with a callback that calls `win32gui.GetWindowText` on each handle until the window title matches a regular expression via `re.match`. Excel probably includes the active spreadsheet name in the window title.

Comment: OK I'll play around with that and see where that gets me.